# selenium - python - find element by inner HTML

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to fetch the following web element using selenium and python

```
<td class="letterbreak first">default</td>
```

And I want to find it based on the inner HTML text `default`. I can't use the class because there are other elements using the same class. I have tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@innerHTML,'default')]")
```

But I get a `NoSuchElementException`.

Is it possible to find based on innerHTML? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: text() instead of @innerHTML should work.

Comment: @arundeepchohan that did not work but driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[text()='default']") did. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either of the xapth.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'default')]")
```

OR

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[text()='default']")
```

---

To avoid synchronization issue induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and following `xpath`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'default')]")))
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: The second format worked but the first did not. Does the first do a partial match and the second an exact match?